# Modal is not opening in boottrap java script file

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently learning the course of front end web developer. I am currently learning about modals. I am pasting my code below. I have uploaded an image of my file structure. I hope someone can find an answer to why my java script is not working. The code worked fine when I linked the code to the CDN javascript file. Please find a solution to my problem in the code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Kitten Portfolio</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img class="title-logo" src="udacity logo.jpg" alt="udacity logo">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
                <h1 class="title-super text-thin">Jane Doette</h1>
                <h4>Front-end Ninja</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placekitten.com/1140/350" alt="Main kitten image">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 class="text-muted">Featured Work</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/555x300" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project1" alt="Appify Kitten Image">
                <h3 class="text-uppercase">Appify</h3>
                <p>https://github.com/udacity/appify</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/555x300" alt="Sunflower Kitten Image">
                <h3 class="text-uppercase">Sunflower</h3>
                <p>https://github.com/udacity/sunflower</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/555x300" alt="Bokeh Kitten Image">
                <h3 class="text-uppercase">Bokeh</h3>
                <p>https://github.com/udacity/bokeh</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="project1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Favorite App Page</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/555.jpeg">
                    This was my first project in this class. I learned a lot about HTML and CSS.
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

File structure:

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

A couple steps in debugging this problem is to have your developer tools open in your browser. First and foremost when you see that the page is not rendering to your assumptions, you need to clarify what you expected to see in order to diagnose well.

Based off some of the things you describe, it may be that the reference to the file is incorrect. To check this, on your developer tools, switch the network tab and press record if not already recording and refresh the page. You may find that there are some 404's showing up that will indicate the page may have the wrong reference to the file.

Next, if there are still problems, your developer tools should inform you of issues in the console output. Try there next.